# Inserting node at the end of a list

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on a program that inserts a node at the end of a given list. For some reason, my code  doesn't work for a list with only one node. Would someone be able to point out why?

```
// Insert a new node containing value at the end of the linked list.
// The head of the new list is returned.
struct node *insert_tail(int value, struct node *head) {
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current = head;
    new->data = value; 

    if (current == NULL) {
        new = head;
        new->next = NULL;
        return new;
    }

    while (current->next != NULL) {
         current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = new;
    new->next = NULL;
    return head; 

}
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. What about new->data = current and then new->next = NULL

Comment: I thought I could just make new->value = head and return the list, but that doesn't seem to work. My list doesn't work for cases where there is only one value, either (i.e. the only element in the list is head).

Comment: I thought that's what I did by writing "new = head." Or do you mean "new->next = head."

Comment: Can I assign it to "current = new" and then "current->next = NULL", "return head"?

Comment: What about for cases where there is only one value in the list, where current->next == NULL.